# Mandar email dependiendo de la fecha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy haciendo una pequeña agenda en Ruby on Rails, actualmente uso UserMailer para mandar correos, pero no encuentro la manera de mandar correo según la fecha de mi evento creado.

Por ejemplo, si creo hoy un evento en mi agenda para dentro de 3 días, quisiera que me mandara un correo el día que empieza el evento.

¿Alguien sabrá como hacer funcionar las condicionales en fecha?

Comment: No se de Ruby pero seguro que los tiros van por incluir un script en cron. Algo parecido a esto https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: Exacto existe una gema para eso el dayler job es fácil

Comment: Hola @Darlyncinho. ¿Podrías especificar qué gema es, quizás con un enlace a https://rubygems.org? Además, si pudieras agregar un pequeño ejemplo de código, sería de gran utilidad para futuros lectores.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el método **deliver_later** de la clase **ActionMailer::MessageDelivery**

Por ejemplo tienes en /mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome(user)
   ...
  end
end
```

Cuando llames al método **welcome** puedes indicar un retraso, por ejemplo en este caso de 3 días

`UserMailer.welcome(User.first).deliver_later(wait: 3.day)`

Más información en [api](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html)

Comment: podría ser, pero mis eventos no son cada 3 días, pienso agendar eventos que sucederían dentro de 1 mes, y quiero q me notifique ese mismo día q evento tengo

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que uses `sidekiq` para manejar tus procesos en modo background, asi evitas que en tu proceso de envio de emails se pierda alguno (entre otras funcionalidades). Esto lo puede usar con `sidetiq` el cual te permite agendar tus trabajos. Para mas información.

- [Sidetiq](https://github.com/endofunky/sidetiq)
- [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Pudieras utilizar un cronjob con la gema [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)
Podria checar todos los dias si tienes un correo a mandar, guardardando cuando se tienen que mandar los correos en una tabla y el job checaria si existe algun correo a mandar cada dia.